# Function will not modify Struct objects that are passed as pointers(or references)

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector

Edit: Code is now runnable

So I am trying to update the position of objects in a struct and I have tested the code within the Update and Rule function both execute and the local variables in the Rule class change as expected. What doesn't change are the member variables of the struct objects of type `Object`.
Here is the relevant code in my cpp file:
struct Object
{
float x;
float y;
float vx;
float vy;
glm::vec4 v_Color;
unsigned int id;

```
  Object(float _x, float _y,
    float _vx, float _vy,
    glm::vec4 _v_Color, unsigned int _id)
    {
      x = _x;
      y = _y;
      vx = _vx;
      vy = _vy;
      v_Color = _v_Color;
      id = _id;
    }
}
std::vector<Object> red;
std::vector<Object> green;
std::vector<Object> blue;
std::vector<Object> yellow;
void Rule(std::vector<Object>* group1, std::vector<Object>* group2, float G)
{
    float g = G;
    for (int i = 0; i < group1->size(); i++) {
        Object p1 = (*group1)[i];
        float fx = 0;
        float fy = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < group2->size(); j++) {
            Object p2 = (*group2)[j];
            float dx = p1.position.x - p2.position.x;
            float dy = p1.position.y - p2.position.y;
            float r = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            if (r < 80 && r > 0) {
                fx += (dx / r);
                fy += (dy / r);
            }
        }

        p1.velocity.x = (p1.velocity.x + fx) * 0.5;
        p1.velocity.y = (p1.velocity.y + fx) * 0.5;
        p1.position.x += p1.velocity.x;
        p1.position.y += p1.velocity.y;
        if ((p1.position.x >= 800) || (p1.position.x <= 0)) { p1.velocity.x *= -1; }
        if ((p1.position.y >= 700) || (p1.position.y <= 0)) { p1.velocity.y *= -1; }
        std::cout << "Calculated velocity: " << fx << ", " << fy << std::endl; // these numbers will change
        (*group1)[i] = p1;
        std::cout << "ID: " << p1.id << ", " << "Velocity " << p1.velocity.x << ", " << p1.velocity.y << "Position: " << p1.position.x << ", " << p1.position.y << std::endl; // you will see these values do not change
    }
}

std::vector<Object> CreateObjects(unsigned int number, glm::vec4 color)
{
    
    std::vector<Object> group;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        float x = rand() % 750 + 50;
        float y = rand() % 550 + 50;
        Object o(x, y, 0, 0, color, objects.size());
        group.push_back(o);
        objects.push_back(o);
    }

    return group;
}

void main()
{
    yellow = CreateObjects(10, glm::vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    blue   = CreateObjects(10, glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    green = CreateObjects(10, glm::vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    red = CreateObjects(10, glm::vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    Rule(&green, &green, -0.32);
    Rule(&green, &red, -0.17);
    Rule(&green, &yellow, 0.34);
    Rule(&red, &red, -0.1);
    Rule(&red, &green, -0.34);
    Rule(&yellow, &yellow, 0.15);
    Rule(&yellow, &green, -0.2);
    Rule(&blue, &green, -0.2);

}
```

Edit: Code should now be runnable

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: I can't run this code, but by inspection it looks like a good example of why I dislike the `auto` keyword: it makes code easier to write but harder to understand. In this case it appears to be hiding the fact that you are modifying *copies* of the `Object` objects you are interested in.

Comment: `auto p1 = (*group1)[i];` --> Try `auto& p1 = (*group1)[i];` and remove `(*group1)[i] = p1;`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The code is runnable now

Comment: No it's not. Do you really believe that if I cut/paste exactly what's shown, into an empty file, it will even compile?

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your program to see in which exact step the program behaves as not expected

pointer to std::vector actually modifies your object.
you should see it if you add another field - int counter in your Object struct

```
struct Object
{
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 velocity;
    glm::vec4 v_Color;
    unsigned int id;
    int counter;  // dont forget to initialise it in Object constructor
```

and here

```
void Rule(std::vector<Object>* group1, std::vector<Object>* group2, float G)
```

simply add

```
p1.counter += 1;
```

Either you actually modify values but presicion is small to notice it. Or there is some kind of mistake on your side. May be glm::vec3 fields x and y should be modified another way than glm::vec3::x += val

P.S
some sources from the internet says that you can access vec3 cooridates but cant change them. Seems like your case

https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/60nsl5/accessing_the_x_y_and_z_values_of_a_vec3_position/

Comment: Still doesnt work when getting rid of the glm::vec3 but I have had luck modifying vec3s with glm for transformations before. the function does not modify any aspect of the object which is very odd. Im wondering if I need to make a vector of object pointers

Comment: i replaced glm::vec3 for int and had no problem with modifying int (position, velocity, v_Color) through your Rule function. So it is about glm::vec3 that is why I asked you to add int counter in struct Object to see that int field actually are modified